# createjs prevent hyperlink interaction

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, createjs, easeljs

In my simple application canvas wrapped by hyperlink. Some objects, which are placed on canvas stage have special mouse interaction on `click` event. Is there any possible solutions to prevent hyperlink jumping by clicking on objects with my mouse click event listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can just call `preventDefault` on the generated mouse event, and it will stop the link event from firing.

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}, false);
```

This is not possible using EaselJS because although you can access the `nativeEvent` on any EaselJS mouse event, EaselJS doesn't use the "click" event at all (and instead uses a combination of "mousedown" and "mouseup"). So preventing default on a click event will do nothing.

#### Doesn't work

```
// You would expect this to work.
myShape.on("click", function(e) {
    e.nativeEvent.preventDefault(); // Nothing. This cancels a "mouseup" instead.
});
```

#### Workaround

However, you can work around this pretty easily. Set a flag on the clicked item (or wherever you would set it in your application) any time it is clicked.

```
myShape.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  myShape.clicked = true;
}, false);
```

Then, listen for the canvas click event yourself, check and check the flag. Make sure to reset it after. This is possible because "click" is always fired after "mouseup"

```
stage.canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     if (myShape.clicked) { event.preventDefault(); }
     myShape.clicked = false;
}, false);
```

Here is a quick fiddle showing it working. http://jsfiddle.net/buqkvb1u/

We are looking to see if this makes sense to handle in EaselJS. Thanks for your report!

Comment: Evaluating a super simple adjustment to EaselJS that would enable this. Might make it an official feature. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your explanation was very helpful!